# Remove commas from Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following JavaScript line of code that removes characters- including commas- from a string:

```
return str.replace(/(?!\/)(?!\ )(?!\-)(\W)/ig, '');
```

How can I only take out the piece of code that removes the commas?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but please provide some more information and expected input and output strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/(?!\/)(?!\ )(?!\-)(\W)/ig` matches any character that is not a "word" character (ie. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and the 3 lookaheads restrict also the character `/`,  and `-`. The comma is removed because it is part of `\W`.

If you want to keep it, add another lookahead: `(?!,)`, then your regex becomes:

```
return str.replace(/(?!\/)(?! )(?!-)(?!,)(\W)/g, '');
```

I've removed the unnecessay escape and the case insensitive flag.

This should be written as:

```
return str.replace(/[^\w\/, -]/g, '');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain why can't I simply remove this part: `\W` from the regex? Could you also explain what you mean by: _I've removed the unnecessary escape and the case insensitive flag._? Thank you!

Comment: @user3378165: In a regex you have to escape certain special characters. Space and dash are not special, so, there're no needs to escape them. You can't remove only `\W` because it rests only 3 negative lookahead that are 0-length match, you can't remove nothing by nothing!

Comment: @user3378165: For some regex basics, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean and http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Working perfectly, thank you so much, I'll look into the attached link, thank you!